# Cloning a 512 bytes per sector HDD to a 4096 bytes per sector SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, disk-cloning

I bought a new SSD to replace my traditional HDD on my Windows 10 laptop. However, it seems my HDD is 512 bytes per sector (from `msinfo32`) and I cannot format the SSD to anything less than 4096 bytes per sector. How do I clone the HDD to the SSD? Do I need to format the SSD with 512 bytes per sector and if yes, how? The Windows format action only seems to support 4096 and higher bytes per sector. It seems popular cloning software [do not support cloning](https://kb.acronis.com/content/45437) between disks that have different bytes per sector. Also, the original HDD is 1TB while the SSD is 500GB.

Comment: "The Windows format action" -- this sounds like you're confusing bytes per disk sector with bytes per filesystem cluster.

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes most likely. `msinfo32` shows the SSD to be 4096 bytes per sector.

Comment: As you plan cloning your hard drive, no need to format the destination drive.

Comment: I would recommend to check the [partition alignment](https://superuser.com/questions/132296/how-to-check-the-partition-alignment-on-an-ssd-drive) of the HDD. If the partitions are proper aligned there is no reason to just clone the HDD to the SSD.

Comment: @electrophile Windows [natively](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) supports this using `Dism` to capture a WIM of the partition(s) you want to move to the new drive, then apply the WIM to the new partition(s), as the vast majority of Windows users have no need for partition-level or disk-level images since NTFS has been the default filesystem since Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Partition-level/disk-level images [contain offset, alignment, block size, etc.] are simply inefficient as NTFS has been the [default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_default_file_systems) filesystem since XP:

- Windows has always natively supported cloning/imaging partitions *(Win ≥8: [`Dism`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) | Win XP ≤7: [`ImageX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx))*, with the vast majority of Windows users having no need for partition-level/disk-level images

---

### PreReqs:

To clone/image the partition(s) from the old HDD to the new drive's partition(s):

- **OS Partition:** 
   This can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE

  - **[WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro):** **Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment 
     Once the Install USB's GUI loads, open a terminal via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
  - **[WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference):** **Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment
- **Any other partition:** <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `Powershell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+OK

To boot to WinRE:

- **Windows ≥8:**

  - *Settings* → *Update & Security* → *Recovery* → *Advanced Startup* → *Troubleshooting* → *Advanced* → *Command Prompt*
  - Login/Lock Screen Power Menu → Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while seleting *Restart* → *Troubleshooting* → *Advanced* → *Command Prompt*
- **Windows 7:** <kbd>F8</kbd> at boot → *Repair your computer* → *Command Prompt*

---

### Partitioning:

1. **Create and format new [partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions):** [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)

   ```powershell
   ::# List disks:
       Lis Dis

   ::# Select OS drive # the image is being applied to:
       Sel Dis #

   ::# Wipe partition table (assumes no data on drive is being preserved)
       Clean
   ```

   **UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   Convert Gpt
   ```
2. **Create [boot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions#system-and-utility-partitions) partition:**

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=100
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=Boot
     Active
     ```
   - **UEFI:** *([EFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#system-partition) | [MSR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions#microsoft-reserved-partition-msr))*

     ```powershell
     Cre Par EFI Offset=1024 Size=100
     Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label=EFI
     Assign Letter=Y
     Cre Par Msr Size=16
     ```
3. **Create [System](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#windows-partition) partition:**

   - **Rest of the drive as the System partition:** 
      *If `C:` can't be assigned, change 3 & 5 to another letter* 
      **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Exit
     ```

     **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Assign Letter=C
     Exit
     ```
   - **Additional [data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions#data-partitions) partitions after the [200GB] System partition:** 
      *If storing User Data directories on a partition other than `C:\` (recommended), max size required is ~300GB* *(multiply size wanted by 1024: `200*1024=204800`)* 
      **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=204800
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     ```

     **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=204800 Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Assign Letter=C
     ```
4. **Create [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#recovery-tools-partition) partition:** *(should have 320MB free to allow for future WIM size increases)*

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Shrink Desired=665 Minimum=650 
     Cre Par Pri id=27
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Shrink Desired=665 Minimum=650
     Cre Par Pri Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
     Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001
     ```
5. **Resolve any boot issues:** *(once system image has been applied)*

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     ::# With existing bootable EFI partition:
         BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD


     ::# Without existing bootable EFI partition:
       ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
           MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
           Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

       ::# Create EFI boot structure:
           BootRec /Fixboot

           ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is applied image):
               BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

       ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
           BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
     ```
6. **Remove EFI mountpoint *(if applicable)* and Reboot 
    UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   DiskPart

     Sel Vol Y
     Remove
     Exit
   ```

---

### Imaging:

<sub>*[(Powershell cmdlet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/use-dism-in-windows-powershell-s14)*</sub>

Specify exclusions or exceptions by creating a [**`WimScript.ini`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) config file, with `/ScratchDir` being required in WinPE since it only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default:

- Even though `/CheckIntegrity` *(`ImageX`: `/Check`)* and `Verify` do extend the image processing time, they should always be used since they prevent corruption from occurring within the WIM/ESD

1. **Either *Capture* or *Append* an image:**

   - **[Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image) a [WIM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096) of the HDD's partitions:**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2021.08.13 @ 09:00" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

     # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
       ImageX /Capture "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2021.08.13 @ 09:00" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
     ```

     - If saving the image to a mechanical HDD, compression takes longer, so if wanting to use `/Compress:Max` or `/Compress:Recovery` and time is an issue, it'll be more efficient to use `/Compress:Fast`, [exporting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image) the image later using *Max* or *Recovery*
     - For managing size constraints, images can be split into multiple read-only `.swm` files via [**`/Split-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#split-image)
   - **[Append Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Append-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2021.08.13 @ 09:00" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

     # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
       ImageX /Append "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2021.08.13 @ 09:00" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
     ```

     - Compression is locked to the value set when the base image was captured
     - Individual indexes can be deleted via [**`/Delete-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#delete-image) or exported to their own image via [**`/Export-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image)
2. **[Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image):**

   ```powershell
   # Windows ≥8: DISM
     Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

   # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
     ImageX /Apply "Z:\Base.wim" 1 "C:" /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
   ```

   - Prior to applying, get [Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo), ensuring correct index [image] is being applied:

     ```powershell
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim"
     ```
   - If applying an OS image, the following must be run prior to exiting WinPE/WinRE:

     - BIOS:

       ```powershell
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```
     - UEFI:

       ```powershell
       ::# With existing bootable EFI partition:
           BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD


       ::# Without existing bootable EFI partition:
           ::# EFI partition mounted at Y:
           ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
               MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
               Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

           ::# Create EFI boot structure:
               BootRec /Fixboot

               ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is applied image):
                   BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

           ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
               BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```

#### Accessing data within a WIM or ESD

1. **Read-only:**

   1. **[Mount Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#mount-image):** *(as `/ReadOnly`)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Optimize /CheckIntegrity /ReadOnly

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Mount "Z:\Base.wim" 2 "C:\Mount" /Check
      ```

      - *In lieu of this, I prefer opening the `.wim`/`.esd` within the [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) GUI*
   2. **[Unmount Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#unmount-image):** *(`/discard` changes)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /CheckIntegrity /Discard

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Unmount "C:\Mount"
      ```
2. **Make changes, or add data, to an image [index]:**

   1. **Mount Image:**

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Optimize /CheckIntegrity

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /MountRW "Z:\Base.wim" 2 "C:\Mount" /Check
      ```
   2. **Unmount Image:** *(`/Commit` changes)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /CheckIntegrity /Commit

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Unmount "C:\Mount" /Commit
      ```

      - If using `DISM`, to save changes as a new appended image, add `/Append`

---

*Additional info: 
 [What is the most efficient, native way to image a Windows partition?](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800)*

Answer (score 0):

See this very similar question :
[512B to 4KiB (Advanced Format) HDD cloning with dd](https://superuser.com/questions/920675/512b-to-4kib-advanced-format-hdd-cloning-with-dd?rq=1)

...and especially Jamie Hanrahan' answer.

You will have to see if you destination SSD is AF (Advanced Format), having 512 bytes emulation (logical sector size of 512).

As for the cloning, you can use Linux's `dd` if you don't need a log file.
Use `ddrescue`, or `hddsuperclone` if you need one.

Comment: I have the perspective it's unacceptable for a Windows user to receive advice to use Linux tools to image Windows, as that's inefficient, forcing the user to rely on not only a non-native boot environment, but also on an image format, unsupported by Windows, both of which over-complicate imaging. _(Ever come across advice telling a BSD or Linux user to boot to Windows or use Wine to back up their data? Normally I'd downvote such advice, but I believe that would be unfair to your answer since I've also posted an answer)_

Comment: @JW0914: No need to use an image format. Just use a live distro that you boot from the DVD bay or a USB key, and use either a dock, an enclosure or an available SATA cable for the second target drive. Really don't understand where is the problem. This is almost daily operation for me.

Comment: Because it's inefficient to use Linux to image/clone Windows partitions, both from a time, and data integrity, perspective, which I cover in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer: a user must create a LiveCD, boot it, look up commands to issue, check parity w/ another program _(automatically done during WIM/ESD capture)_, then once completed, if a system partition was cloned the user will likely need to boot to WinRE to run `BootRec`. To image from Windows takes less time, has parity, and doesn't require an incompatible boot environment or need for a partition/disk-level clone.